# SAS bar charts - horizontal and vertical

Tags: sas

For the baseball data table containing both league and batting average variables for both leagues, construct

1. Part A: A horizontal bar chart of batting averages for each of the leagues, including summary statistics (two charts), keep the midpoints and axes for the two charts uniform so that comparisons can be made between two leagues
2. Part C: A vertical bar chart of league showing the mean/average of batting averages for each league. That’s to say, the height of bars is the mean of batting averages

My Code:

```
data HW6; 
  input battingaverage League $16.; 
datalines; 
211 National League 233 National League 248 National League 259 National League 259 National League 262 National League 270 National League 243 American League 255 American League 269 American League 267 American League 275 American League 279 American League 277 American League
run; 

Proc sort data=HW6; 
  By league; 
run;
```

Part A:

```
Proc gchart data=HW6; 
  By league; 
  hbar battingaverage axis=10 20 30; 
run;quit;
```

Part C:

```
Proc gchart data=HW6; 
  vbar league;
```

My question for part A why do you use proc sort and kind of a dumb question how are you suppose to choose which axis's to use?

For part C I have no idea what is being asked and how to proceed with answering the question.

Comment: You're learning `PROC GCHART` in a class?  You might want to consider changing schools.  `PROC GCHART` is extremely outdated ... no-one should be learning it nowadays, instead learn `SGPLOT`.

Comment: Yeah and haha believe me the math department here is beyond abysmal I'm not surprised to hear that luckily this is my last year. Btw thanks a bunch for the help on the code! Everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer A, you want to use `group` not `by` to keep the midpoints/etc. the same.  BY will give you multiple charts with independent axes.

```
proc gchart data=HW6;
  hbar battingaverage/group=league;
run;quit;
```

You `sort` because that enables the `by` statement. You don't have to do that using `group`.  I don't know if you can get two actual separate charts easily using the same midpoints (and `by`), so if your professor really wants that, well, they should use `sgplot`.

To answer C, you should start by looking at the `mean` keyword, and perhaps the `sumvar` keyword.